# Set ringtone / notification tone via contentprovider (from assets)

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone

I'm trying to set the android default ringtone or notification tone via content provider from my assets folder.
Surprisingly, it works like this, but **is it a legitimate way?**

```
Uri audiouri = Uri.parse("content://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/"+soundname+".mp3");
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(a, TYPE_NOTIFICATION, audiouri );
```

Unfortunately, the sound name isn't shown in Android settings.
[image]

Strangely the sound name is actually shown when I go to 'Other sounds'
[image]

### I also tried this:

```
Uri audiouri = Uri.parse("content://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/"+soundname+".mp3");
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
Uri ringtoneuri = a.getContentResolver().insert(audiouri, contentValues);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(a, TYPE_NOTIFICATION, ringtoneuri);
```

resulting in a null sound (no sound is set)

### third option I tried is:

```
Uri audiouri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath("content://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/"+soundname+".mp3");
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, "content://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/"+soundname+".mp3");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
Uri ringtoneuri = a.getContentResolver().insert(audiouri, contentValues);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(a, TYPE_NOTIFICATION, ringtoneuri);
```

Now the **sound name is shown correctly, but no sound is actually played.**
I get error on logcat:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Can't access /content:/com.mydomain.myapp/test.mp3

So it seems it's taking the value from MediaColumns.DATA which does not support Content provider paths but only real paths. Right?

[image]

**Final question: How to set tone AND name in android settings? Preferably without copying the file to external storage.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, unfortunately I did not find out how to set asset as ringtone directly,
but this is a nice workaround:

When copying asset to **internal app storage or cache dir** (no permissions needed for that!) I was able to set the ringtone without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permisson.

```
static void settone(int type, Sound sound, Activity a)
{
    lastsound = sound; //global remember sound and type (alarm/ringtone/notification) 
    lasttype = type;   // if we have to get permissions first, then call this from onActivityResult
    if (canwritesystem(a))
    {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(a, type, getringtoneuri(sound, a));
        Toast.makeText(a, a.getString(R.string.settonesuccess), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else a.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).setData(Uri.parse("package:" + a.getPackageName())),CONTEXT_SET_TONE);
}

static Uri getringtoneuri(Sound sound, Activity a)
{
    File tonefile = new File(sound.getpath); // path could be like: /Android/data/com.company.yourapp
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, tonefile.getAbsolutePath());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, sound.getDisplayName());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, tonefile.length());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
    Uri generalaudiouri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    a.getContentResolver().delete(generalaudiouri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "='" + tonefile.getAbsolutePath() + "'", null);
    return a.getContentResolver().insert(generalaudiouri, contentValues);
}
```